# Remove data from log on cancellation

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that colours in a row of information and then stores the date and the user that coloured in said row of information on a log.

That is all well and good but I would like to somehow figure out how to reverse said process. Currently if you use the code again on the same selection the colour changes back to 'no fill' but unfortunately I'm not sure how to remove that same information that was sent to the log initially. Any ideas?

```
Sub CompleteLine()
Dim RCount As Integer

RCount = Selection.Columns.Count
If Selection.Interior.Color = 5296274 Then
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

Else

If RCount = 16384 And Selection.Interior.Color <> 5296274 Then
Selection.Interior.Color = 5296274
    With Sheets("Log")
    .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1) = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    .Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Offset(1) = Environ("Username")
End With
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. There is room for improvement, but it should work. It should at least get you started

```
Sub CompleteLine()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

Dim RCount As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim checkC As Boolean

    RCount = Selection.Columns.Count
        With Selection
            If .Interior.Color = 5296274 Then
               .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
               checkC = False
            Else
            If RCount = 16384 And .Interior.Color <> 5296274 Then .Interior.Color = 5296274
               checkC = True
            End If
        End With
             
            With Sheets("Log")
            lastrow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
            If checkC = True Then
                .Range("A" & lastrow & ":A" & lastrow) = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                .Range("B" & lastrow & ":B" & lastrow) = Environ("Username")
            Else
            If checkC = False Then .Range("A" & lastrow & ":B" & lastrow - 1).ClearContents
            End If
            End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```